# Java OR operator in if string contains statement

Tags: java, string, contains

I have the following code.

```
for (String str5 : verticesposition2) {
    if(!str5.contains(("Vertex")||("Name")||("Transmittance")) {
        System.out.println(str5); 
    }                           
}
```

As you can see above if the string does NOT contain Vertex, Name or Transmittance I want it to print out. However Im getting a compilation error saying that the || operator is undefined for the argument types. I'm relatively new to programming so Im not sure what this means could someone kindly point in the right direction on how to fix my code?

Comment: string contains can be only used with CharSequence. your input in the bracket is not CharSequence. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29   and  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The || operator works on individual boolean terms, not to provide a bunch of different arguments.

```
if((!str5.contains("Vertex")||!str5.contains("Name")||!str5.contains("Transmittance")){
```

Comment: its logically wrong. it should be: `if((!str5.contains("Vertex")&&!str5.contains("Name")&&!str5.contains("Transmittance"))` because the OP want to know if the string contain not one of the words.

Comment: @WhoAmI His statement is `true` if the `str5` not contains `"Vertext"` for example, but it should only be true if `str5` not contains any of the three words-

Answer (score 17):

Java doesn't have a syntax like that, but you can put the  "or" in a regex:

```
if (!str5.matches(".*(Vertex|Name|Transmittance).*")) {
```

Note that java's `matches()` (unlike many other languages) must match the *whole* string to return true, hence the `.*` at each end of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

try to use this code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> verticesposition2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        verticesposition2.add("safdsfVertex");
        verticesposition2.add("safdsfNamesfsd");
        verticesposition2.add("notCONTAINS");

        for (String str5 : verticesposition2){
            if(!(str5.contains("Vertex")||str5.contains("Name")||str5.contains("Transmittance"))){
                System.out.println(str5);
            }
        }
    }
```

Output:

notCONTAINS

if speed isn't critical -- use those with regexp.